# Updating registry `https://example.com/`

Tags: rust

As https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto says, I added this to my rust-lib project:

```
//Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
rust-crypto = "*"

//lib.rs
extern crate "rust-crypto" as rust_crypto;
```

And got this:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry `https://example.com/`
Unable to update the package registry

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://example.com/`

Caused by:
  [16] hostname does not match certificate
```

There's no "example.com" neither my project, nor in his lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're being downvoted.

You may just have an older Cargo, when the registry was set to example.com. When did you last install it?

See also: this reddit thread http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2mywa1/cargo_update_error_on_registry_httpsexamplecom/

Comment: Regarding the downvotes, I found people are quick to downvote on Rust questions compared to let's say C#.

Comment: :( I must come along later, then, I usually see them in the positives.